# Eliminate Gaps in Primary Key Field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key

I'm in the process of building a database in MS Access (SQL Server Compatible Syntax enabled) and I'm having a question regarding my primary keys. Specifically, I would like to find a way to eliminate the gaps in primary keys so that the keys will be continuous, even after a record has been deleted. I don't think that this should create referential integrity issues, as foreign keys are set to ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Note: I'm writing the table creation statements in SQL, so I can code the solution in a SQL script and run it.

Is there a built in function that can accomplish this, or is there a trigger/stored procedure that I should create?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good idea. Why would you want to update your primary key values?

Comment: Each record can also be referenced, in conversation, by its primary key. For example, you could say, "Lets talk about record #1." Making another column to describe the numbering/ordering of the records would not solve the problem, as I would still have to find a way to remove gaps from that column when a record is deleted.

Comment: See my answer below but why on earth do you want to do this? Any logical reason?

Comment: The PK/number of each record is shown alongside the other data in each record and the record can be referred to by its #. Its kind of like if I had a table containing a list of rules. I wouldn't want the list to read 1, 2, 4.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. A auto-number/identity primary key cannot be reused. There is no performance loss by having gaps so no harm done. Just leave it as is no problems. This will create a massive update and reorganization of your database. The gaps are normal for any database engine where a insert failed for example. Oracle, MySQl and SQL Server all do this.